# (Remix IDE) Code Completion not showing up. Can you help me?

Tags: remix, ide

[image: remix ide code completion]

(Remix IDE) Code Completion not showing up. Can you help me?

Comment: maybe change the compiler version`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

GoTo -> **Remix-IDE Setting Left-Bottom**
Show the CheckBox -> **Enable code completion in editor.**  Click to check.